# RAM usage discrepancy - processes don't add up

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance

Noticing issues with RAM usage on laptops. Windows 10 x64.

The RAM usage on the performance tab does not match that on the user tab of Task Manager.
If I add up all processes on process tab, they don't match the total on the performance tab.

[image: 12gb usage in performance]

[image: 5gb usage for only logged in user]

This is something I haven't experienced before but it's causing us issues with RAM being totally filled even then a computer isn't really doing much. My system has 16gb but we're seeing it on machines that have 8gb which leaves little to no headroom.

EDIT: Finding that we're hitting max RAM usage basically, despite the user doing very little. On 8GB RAM systems, it's topping out and actually giving low memory warnings/chugging even though it's just Office open and a couple of Chrome tabs. Looking at the users tab, of course they will be sat at around 1-1.5gb of RAM, but the performance tab shows 7.9gb used. Their processes don't add up to 7.9gb, but about 1-1.5gb. I'll add a RAMMap screenshot.

Any pointers on how this could be diagnosed?

RAMMAP tells me theres 10gb of 'Process Private', 5gb of 'mapped file'.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? Are you running into hard slowdown with swap, or is it that you just think the system ought to waste some memory just so the graphs look nicer?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a RAMMap screenshot. And do you have a swap file and what is its size?

Comment: The difference is 1% of your memory and 6% of your CPU I would agree we need RAMMap screenshots

Comment: Finding that we're hitting max RAM usage basically, despite the user doing very little. On 8GB RAM systems, it's topping out and actually giving low memory warnings/chugging even tough it's just Office open and a couple of Chrome tabs. Looking at the users tab, of course they will be sat at around 1-1.5gb of RAM, but the performance tab shows 7.9gb used. Their processes don't add up to 7.9gb, but about 1-1.5gb. I'll add a RAMMap screenshot.